# How can the same set of dependent filters be used with two datasets to generate at least two outputs?

Tags: r, filter, shiny, dependencies, render

I am a volunteer for a start-up, non-profit that solicits contributions of mineral interests from private royalty *owners*. Contributed interests are then aggregated and sold with the proceeds awarded as grants to promote the development of technologies to fight climate change.

To expand our fund-raising efforts, we want to set up a shiny web app for *owners* who could be prospective donors. These *owners* could search our database, locate their interests and learn the amount of tax deduction they could gain through a donation to our non-profit (First Objective, based on "Sample_Tax_Data", see: (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wKe9VR_Cs2V_CJGNipbuCaUFR21eTHE0/edit?usp=share_link&ouid=118028955904508148375&rtpof=true&sd=trueto)).

*Owners* could also access alternative valuations, based upon historical oil and gas production associated with their Lease, that could increase the amount of their tax deduction for those Leases with additional development potential (Second Objective based upon "Sample_Prod_Data", see (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Pq6bfiaATGZaGHtxOrqekJjTp4g3k_Rj/edit?usp=share_link&ouid=118028955904508148375&rtpof=true&sd=true)).

**In the case of the First Objective**:
Using code I found on this site (see below), I was able to create a series of dependent filters that enable *owners* to sort through the 10 million lease interests in our database to locate their particular lease(s).

```r
library(readxl)
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

TaxData <- Sample_Tax_Data

shinyApp(
  ui = pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel("Find My Royalty Interest"),
    sidebarPanel(
      selectizeInput(inputId = "County",
                     label = "Select County",
                     choices = NULL,
                     options = list(placeholder = 'select')
                     ),
      
      selectizeInput(inputId = "Operator",
                     label = "Select Operator",
                     choices = NULL,
                     options = list(placeholder = 'select',
                                    onInitialize = I('function() { this.setValue(""); }')
                     )),
      
      selectizeInput(inputId = "Lease",
                     label = "Select Lease",
                     choices = NULL,
                     options = list(placeholder = 'select',
                                    onInitialize = I('function() { this.setValue(""); }')
                     )),
      
      selectizeInput(inputId = "Owner",
                     label = "Select Owner",
                     choices = NULL,
                     options = list(placeholder = 'select',
                                    onInitialize = I('function() { this.setValue(""); }')
                     )),
      
       ),
    
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("TaxTable")
    )
  ),
  
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    
    TaxFil <- reactive({
      
      TaxData %>%
        filter(County == input$County) %>%
        filter(Operator == input$Operator) %>%
        filter(Lease == input$Lease) %>%
        filter(Owner == input$Owner) 
      
   })
    
    updateSelectizeInput(
      session = session,
      inputId = "County",
      choices = sort(unique(as.character(TaxData$County))),
      selected = "",
      options = list(placeholder = 'select'),
      server = TRUE
    )
    
    observeEvent(input$County,{
      choice_Operator <- sort(unique(as.character(TaxData$Operator[which(TaxData$County==input$County)])))
      
      updateSelectizeInput(
        session = session,
        inputId = "Operator",
        choices = choice_Operator
      )
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$Operator,{
      choice_Lease <- sort(unique(as.character(TaxData$Lease[which(TaxData$County==input$County &
                                                                     TaxData$Operator==input$Operator)])))
      
      updateSelectizeInput(
        session = session,
        inputId = "Lease",
        choices = choice_Lease
      )
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$Lease,{
      choice_Owner <- sort(unique(as.character(TaxData$Owner[which(TaxData$County==input$County &
                                                                     TaxData$Operator==input$Operator &
                                                                     TaxData$Lease==input$Lease)])))
      
      updateSelectizeInput(
        session = session,
        inputId = "Owner",
        choices = choice_Owner
      )
    })
    
    output$TaxTable <- renderTable({TaxFil()})
    
  },
  
  options = list(height = 500)
  
)
```

**In the case of the Second Objective:**
I have not been able to write the code to support the use of that same series of dependent filters, and the results therefrom, to enable *owners* to access the alternative valuations associated with their interests.

The first option I considered was a re-use of the filters supporting the First Objective (see code above). In such case, the filters would be used to identify both the *Owner* (and the assigned "Tax Value"-first objective) as well as the Lease (and the production of "Oil" and "Gas" therefrom for purposes of projecting additional value-second objective). This seemed like it would be the most logical way to filter for the Two Objectives, but I couldn't get it to work.

The next thing I tried was to recreate the filter and use it separately for the Second Objective (with the original filter just being used for purposes of selecting the *Owner*.) I could't get this to work either and it also did not seem like a very economical coding option anyway.

The final thing I tried was a merger of the two data bases. But with many leases having over 30 years of monthly production history and thousands of *owners* in some cases, the combined file would be at least 20 times bigger and difficult to work with.

So in summary, I am looking for help coding one set of filters that can be applied to at least two different databases for at least two different outputs. I have reviewed previous questions/answers and found several that are close in nature, such as those answered by NicE, but with my limited experience I couldn't extrapolate to my particular objective. I am obviously new to this and would really appreciate your support.

Answer (score 0):

To reuse the same set of filters, you should first determine the valid set
of values from the union of the common filtering columns:

```r
library(readr)
library(dplyr) # union.data.frame

TaxData <- read_tsv("https://pastebin.com/raw/eiFFTmuh", show_col_types = FALSE)
ProdData <- read_tsv("https://pastebin.com/raw/kCWZ9bd5", show_col_types = FALSE)
ProdData$Date <- lubridate::mdy(ProdData$Date)

cols <- c("County", "Operator", "Lease")
Leases <- union(TaxData[cols], ProdData[cols])
Leases
#> # A tibble: 5 × 3
#>   County   Operator Lease
#>   <chr>    <chr>    <chr>
#> 1 Goliad   BP       G1   
#> 2 Goliad   Shell    G2   
#> 3 Live Oak Tex      L1   
#> 4 Live Oak Conoco   L4   
#> 5 Shell    Shell    G2
```

Then to update the set of choices for each filter based on earlier selections,
filter this shared set as far as you can. Swap the data you use to update
choices once you encounter columns that are present in only one of the
datasets (like Owner here).

Here’s a demo app of how I’d put this into action. First, I condensed the UI
a bit:

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("Find My Royalty Interest"),
  sidebarPanel(
    lapply(c("County", "Operator", "Lease", "Owner"), function(field) {
      selectizeInput(
        inputId = field,
        label = paste("Select ", field),
        choices = NULL,
        options = list(placeholder = "Select")
      )
    })
  ),
  mainPanel(
    tableOutput("TaxTable"),
    plotOutput("ProdGraph")
  )
)
```

Next, a couple of helper functions for common server tasks:

```r
get_inputs <- function(..., session = getDefaultReactiveDomain()) {
  lapply(setNames(nm = c(...)), function(id) session$input[[id]])
}

update_choices <- function(id, data, ..., session = getDefaultReactiveDomain()) {
  choices <- sort(unique(data[[id]]))
  updateSelectizeInput(session, id, choices = choices, selected = "", ...)
}
```

And finally, the revised server. Here we make liberal use of `merge()` to
do the filtering instead of explicitly writing out all the `==` comparisons.

```r
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  update_choices("County", Leases, server = TRUE)

  observeEvent(input$County, {
    update_choices("Operator", merge(Leases, get_inputs("County")))
  })

  observeEvent(input$Operator, {
    update_choices("Lease", merge(Leases, get_inputs("County", "Operator")))
  })

  observeEvent(input$Lease, {
    update_choices("Owner", merge(TaxData, get_inputs("County", "Operator", "Lease")))
  })

  output$TaxTable <- renderTable({
    merge(TaxData, Filter(nzchar, get_inputs("County", "Operator", "Lease", "Owner")))
  })

  output$ProdGraph <- renderPlot({
    ProdFil <- merge(ProdData, get_inputs("County", "Operator", "Lease"))
    ProdFil <- ProdFil[order(ProdFil$Date), ]
    req(nrow(ProdFil) > 0) # Only plot if we have some matching rows
    plot(`Oil/bbl` ~ Date, ProdFil, type = "b")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

When playing around with this, I found it more intuitive to have the incrementally
filtered data show up as different filters are applied. If the real data are too
large to send before being fully filtered, you could drop the `Filter`s. Or show a
truncated preview to still give an impression of things happening to the user.

Comment: Mikko, I can't say that I totally understand what you have done but it does work. I would like to show a graph of Oil and/or Gas production as a function of time for the selected Lease, as opposed to a table. If you could help me with that I would appreciate it. In the mean time I will be studying your code and will get back with any questions. I do appreciate your help!

Comment: Of course, David. Is there something in particular that you are struggling with in creating a graph? As I see it, there's nothing substantially different with creating a graph in this app than in any other app.

Comment: For the plot of oil production by month produced and representing production from the Lease of the selected Owner, I have tried the following code:

Comment: output$ProdPlot <- renderPlot({
    plot((merge(ProdData,Filter(nzchar, get_inputs("County", "Operator", "Lease")))), ProdData$Date,        ProdData$Oil, main = "Scatter Plot", xlab = "Date", ylab = "Oil/bbl")
  })

Comment: then for the Main Panel:

Comment: plotOutput("ProdPlot").  As you probably can guess this is not working. I can not figure out how to generate a plot of just the Lease that is owned by the selected Owner. Also, the plot should not appear until the "Lease" has been selected. Any suggestions?

Comment: Also, I am going to make a test run with one County, which will have about 1,000 "Leases" and 3,000 "Owners". I will let you know how it goes.

Comment: You'll need to assign the result of the merge, and use that data frame for the plot. In the code it looks like you are attempting to use the original unfiltered data. To stop plotting until a Lease is selected, remove the `Filter` and add a `req()` to check that your filtered data has some rows in it before plotting. I've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Mikko, I tested your edits with an expanded data base (see links below) and I could not get passed the County filter using the viewer. I compared this expanded data set to the Sample set and the formatting appears the same so I can't understand what has happened. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_Br1S3sVjuWqIkwKPS9xvtaR5pL9Cgmo/edit?usp=share_link&ouid=118028955904508148375&rtpof=true&sd=true                                             https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1u-6yAxQgsdmwqqjK48xmDjLx0Heb1ZJY/edit?usp=share_link&ouid=118028955904508148375&rtpof=true&sd=true

Comment: Could you elaborate on what's happening? One thing that comes to mind is if you don't have `dplyr` loaded the `union` will produce a result that can't be used for filtering. As for the linked data, it appears to be access restricted.

Comment: I believe the problem relates to my use of just one County (LA SALLE) in the expanded database as opposed to the two Counties in the original sample database (Goliad & Live Oak). The updated code works fine with the sample database but freezes after entering "LA SALLE" with the expanded database. Thanks so much for your help, Mikko and I will be getting back to you with new questions, if you don't mind.

Comment: Nope that was not the problem. I simply wasn't waiting long enough for the program to load all of the data. That might be a problem as the full data set is many times larger than even the "expanded" data set I have been using. Thanks again for all your help, Mikko

Comment: Was the slow part in loading the data from a file to memory, or the filtering? There's definitely optimisations that could be applied to the filtering logic, for example to avoid merges that are known to produce empty results. Another avenue you might want to investigate would be to store the datasets in a simple SQLite database file and query that instead of loading the full data into memory.